# Cylinder follow end of animation path

Tags: animation, path

Hi I am trying to create an animated logo were the border starts from the top centre and draws around the perimeter and nearly meets at the bottom.

I have this working ok.

Next I have added a small cylinder and added an emission shader, trying to give a glow effect at the point the border is increasing.

My cylinder follows the path although not from the top middle were the animated border starts from.  How do I get the cylinder to start at the same point the border animation starts from?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I started this answer, I thought: 'Instance objects on the ends of trimmed curves in Geometry Nodes, and it will save work'. Only one place to key-frame (The 'End' parameter) .. nothing to sync up.. all procedural..

[image]

.. but by the time all the tweaking is over, I'm not sure it saves time, for a one-off. Anyway.. here it is:

[image]

The group should be adaptable to your purposes, by modifying your 2-spline curve with it, replacing the 'Ball' object with your cylinder, and using your own materials.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must have clicked on the *Animate Path* button of the *Follow Path* constraint of your small cylinder, which generates a modifier that moves the object along the curve. First thing, delete it in the *Graph Editor*:

[image]

Instead use the *Evaluation Time* value of the curve to move your cylinder, at frame 1 create a keyframe so that the cylinder is at the top center position (*Evaluation Time* should be around 48):

[image]

At the end of the animation create a second keyframe with the value of the *Evaluation Time* at 0:

[image]

You'll need to create some intermediate keyframes so that the cylinder moves as fast as the curve *End* value.